# XSLT How to Transform XML into new element groups and attributes

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0

I have been struggling trying to figure out how to transform an XML by using XSLT.  The main goal is to take the XML source data and have it repeat/create new rows based on the months data.  For instance currently each row has "X" amount of months data all as one row.  I am trying to break this out so that each row only contains a single months worth of data.  Then the next row would contain the same header information but the next months data for the original source row.  Hopefully that makes sense.  I also am trying to figure out how to configure the month column in a row to trigger a new value for the numeric value of that month as a new value within the target XML as seen in my example.  Any suggestions would be greatly appreciative.

Source Code:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="txt/xsl" href="transform.xsl"?>
<Report>
<ReportData>
<DataSet>
<Row rowNum="1">
<Column name="Title 1"><Val xsi:type="xsd:string">Sample 1</Val></Column>
<Column name="Title 2"><Val xsi:type="xsd:string">Sample 2</Val></Column>
<Column name="Title 3"><Val xsi:type="xsd:string">Sample 3</Val></Column>
<Column name="Title 4"><Val xsi:type="xsd:string">Sample 4</Val></Column>
<Column name="Title 5"><Val xsi:type="xsd:string">160X600</Val></Column>
<Column name="Title 6"><Val xsi:type="xsd:string" xsi:nil="true"></Val></Column>
<Column name="Title 7"><Val xsi:type="xsd:integer">1325600</Val></Column>
<Column name="MAR_Month_Total"><Val xsi:type="xsd:float">19.00</Val></Column>
<Column name="MAR_Month_Total_B"><Val xsi:type="xsd:float">22.00</Val></Column>
<Column name="APR_Month_Total"><Val xsi:type="xsd:float">18.00</Val></Column>
<Column name="APR_Month_Total_B"><Val xsi:type="xsd:float">35.00</Val></Column>
<Column name="MAY_Month_Total"><Val xsi:type="xsd:float">25.00</Val></Column>
<Column name="MAY_Month_Total_B"><Val xsi:type="xsd:float">15.00</Val></Column>
</Row>
<RowNum="2">
<Column name="Title 1"><Val xsi:type="xsd:string">Sample 5</Val></Column>
<Column name="Title 2"><Val xsi:type="xsd:string">Sample 6</Val></Column>
<Column name="Title 3"><Val xsi:type="xsd:string">Sample 7</Val></Column>
<Column name="Title 4"><Val xsi:type="xsd:string">Sample 8</Val></Column>
<Column name="Title 5"><Val xsi:type="xsd:string">250X600</Val></Column>
<Column name="Title 6"><Val xsi:type="xsd:string" xsi:nil="true"></Val></Column>
<Column name="Title 7"><Val xsi:type="xsd:integer">5600</Val></Column>
<Column name="MAR_Month_Total"><Val xsi:type="xsd:float">0.00</Val></Column>
<Column name="MAR_Month_Total_B"><Val xsi:type="xsd:float">5.00</Val></Column>
<Column name="APR_Month_Total"><Val xsi:type="xsd:float">24.00</Val></Column>
<Column name="APR_Month_Total_B"><Val xsi:type="xsd:float">10.00</Val></Column>
<Column name="MAY_Month_Total"><Val xsi:type="xsd:float">36.00</Val></Column>
<Column name="MAY_Month_Total_B"><Val xsi:type="xsd:float">15.00</Val></Column></Row>
</DataSet>
</ReportData>
</Report>
```

Example of Results XML

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="txt/xsl" href="transform.xsl"?>
<Report>
<ReportData>
<DataSet>
<Row rowNum="1">
<Column name="Title 1"><Val xsi:type="xsd:string">Sample 1</Val></Column>
<Column name="Title 2"><Val xsi:type="xsd:string">Sample 2</Val></Column>
<Column name="Title 3"><Val xsi:type="xsd:string">Sample 3</Val></Column>
<Column name="Title 4"><Val xsi:type="xsd:string">Sample 4</Val></Column>
<Column name="Title 5"><Val xsi:type="xsd:string">160X600</Val></Column>
<Column name="Title 6"><Val xsi:type="xsd:string" xsi:nil="true"></Val></Column>
<Column name="Title 7"><Val xsi:type="xsd:integer">1325600</Val></Column>
<Column name="MAR_Month_ID"><Val xsi:type="xsd:integer">3</Val></Column>
<Column name="YEAR"><Val xsi:type="xsd:integer">2012</Val></Column>
<Column name="MAR_Month_Total"><Val xsi:type="xsd:float">19.00</Val></Column>
<Column name="MAR_Month_Total_B"><Val xsi:type="xsd:float">22.00</Val></Column>
</Row>
<Row rowNum="2">
<Column name="Title 1"><Val xsi:type="xsd:string">Sample 1</Val></Column>
<Column name="Title 2"><Val xsi:type="xsd:string">Sample 2</Val></Column>
<Column name="Title 3"><Val xsi:type="xsd:string">Sample 3</Val></Column>
<Column name="Title 4"><Val xsi:type="xsd:string">Sample 4</Val></Column>
<Column name="Title 5"><Val xsi:type="xsd:string">160X600</Val></Column>
<Column name="Title 6"><Val xsi:type="xsd:string" xsi:nil="true"></Val></Column>
<Column name="Title 7"><Val xsi:type="xsd:integer">1325600</Val></Column>
<Column name="APR_Month_ID"><Val xsi:type="xsd:integer">4</Val></Column>
<Column name="YEAR"><Val xsi:type="xsd:integer">2012</Val></Column>
<Column name="APR_Month_Total"><Val xsi:type="xsd:float">18.00</Val></Column>
<Column name="APR_Month_Total_B"><Val xsi:type="xsd:float">35.00</Val></Column>
</Row>
<Row rowNum="3">
<Column name="Title 1"><Val xsi:type="xsd:string">Sample 1</Val></Column>
<Column name="Title 2"><Val xsi:type="xsd:string">Sample 2</Val></Column>
<Column name="Title 3"><Val xsi:type="xsd:string">Sample 3</Val></Column>
<Column name="Title 4"><Val xsi:type="xsd:string">Sample 4</Val></Column>
<Column name="Title 5"><Val xsi:type="xsd:string">160X600</Val></Column>
<Column name="Title 6"><Val xsi:type="xsd:string" xsi:nil="true"></Val></Column>
<Column name="Title 7"><Val xsi:type="xsd:integer">1325600</Val></Column>
<Column name="MAY_Month_ID"><Val xsi:type="xsd:integer">5</Val></Column>
<Column name="YEAR"><Val xsi:type="xsd:integer">2012</Val></Column>
<Column name="MAY_Month_Total"><Val xsi:type="xsd:float">25.00</Val></Column>
<Column name="MAY_Month_Total_B"><Val xsi:type="xsd:float">15.00</Val></Column>
</Row>
<Row RowNum="4">
<Column name="Title 1"><Val xsi:type="xsd:string">Sample 5</Val></Column>
<Column name="Title 2"><Val xsi:type="xsd:string">Sample 6</Val></Column>
<Column name="Title 3"><Val xsi:type="xsd:string">Sample 7</Val></Column>
<Column name="Title 4"><Val xsi:type="xsd:string">Sample 8</Val></Column>
<Column name="Title 5"><Val xsi:type="xsd:string">250X600</Val></Column>
<Column name="Title 6"><Val xsi:type="xsd:string" xsi:nil="true"></Val></Column>
<Column name="Title 7"><Val xsi:type="xsd:integer">5600</Val></Column>
<Column name="MAR_Month_ID"><Val xsi:type="xsd:integer">3</Val></Column>
<Column name="YEAR"><Val xsi:type="xsd:integer">2012</Val></Column>
<Column name="MAR_Month_Total"><Val xsi:type="xsd:float">0.00</Val></Column>
<Column name="MAR_Month_Total_B"><Val xsi:type="xsd:float">5.00</Val></Column>
</Row>
<Row RowNum="5">
<Column name="Title 1"><Val xsi:type="xsd:string">Sample 5</Val></Column>
<Column name="Title 2"><Val xsi:type="xsd:string">Sample 6</Val></Column>
<Column name="Title 3"><Val xsi:type="xsd:string">Sample 7</Val></Column>
<Column name="Title 4"><Val xsi:type="xsd:string">Sample 8</Val></Column>
<Column name="Title 5"><Val xsi:type="xsd:string">250X600</Val></Column>
<Column name="Title 6"><Val xsi:type="xsd:string" xsi:nil="true"></Val></Column>
<Column name="Title 7"><Val xsi:type="xsd:integer">5600</Val></Column>
<Column name="APR_Month_ID"><Val xsi:type="xsd:integer">4</Val></Column>
<Column name="YEAR"><Val xsi:type="xsd:integer">2012</Val></Column>
<Column name="APR_Month_Total"><Val xsi:type="xsd:float">18.00</Val></Column>
<Column name="APR_Month_Total_B"><Val xsi:type="xsd:float">35.00</Val></Column>
</Row>
<Row rowNum"6">
<Column name="Title 1"><Val xsi:type="xsd:string">Sample 5</Val></Column>
<Column name="Title 2"><Val xsi:type="xsd:string">Sample 6</Val></Column>
<Column name="Title 3"><Val xsi:type="xsd:string">Sample 7</Val></Column>
<Column name="Title 4"><Val xsi:type="xsd:string">Sample 8</Val></Column>
<Column name="Title 5"><Val xsi:type="xsd:string">250X600</Val></Column>
<Column name="Title 6"><Val xsi:type="xsd:string" xsi:nil="true"></Val></Column>
<Column name="Title 7"><Val xsi:type="xsd:integer">5600</Val></Column>
<Column name="MAY_Month_ID"><Val xsi:type="xsd:integer">5</Val></Column>
<Column name="YEAR"><Val xsi:type="xsd:integer">2012</Val></Column>
<Column name="MAY_Month_Total"><Val xsi:type="xsd:float">18.00</Val></Column>
<Column name="MAY_Month_Total_B"><Val xsi:type="xsd:float">35.00</Val></Column>
</ROW>
</DataSet>
</ReportData>
</Report>
```

Appreciate any assistance.
Thanks

Comment: Two questions: 1. Will always a month occupy two consecutive columns, or could there be different number of consecutive columns for a month? 2. Ehere do you take the Year from -- there isn't any such data in the provided XML document.

Comment: Yes.  There will always be two columns for month sales values.  One is for Gross the other is for net.  Plus the one column for MonthID.  Year is always going to the current year of the report being ran.  thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<!--- you need to complete this variable with all month keys: -->
<xsl:variable name="monthCodes" select="('JAN','FEB','MAR','APR','MAY','...')"/>
<xsl:template match="Row">
    <!-- saves the month-total columns in a variable-->
    <xsl:variable name="months" select="Column[contains(@name,'Month_Total')]"/>
    <!-- groups the $months: starts a new group, if the @name is matching on the regex 'Month_Total$' -->
    <xsl:for-each-group select="$months" group-starting-with="*[matches(@name,'Month_Total$')]">
        <Row>
            <xsl:variable name="rowNum" select="count(../preceding-sibling::Row/Column[matches(@name,'Month_Total$')]) + position()"/>
            <xsl:attribute name="rowNum" select="$rowNum"/>
            <!-- copies all Columns of the current <Row> witch are not in $months -->
            <xsl:copy-of select="../Column[not(contains(@name,'Month_Total'))]"/>
            <xsl:variable name="monthCode" select="substring(@name,1,3)"/>
            <Column name="{$monthCode}_Month_ID">
                <Val xsi:type="xsd:integer">
                    <xsl:value-of select="index-of($monthCodes,$monthCode)"/>
                </Val>
            </Column>
            <Column name="YEAR">
                <Val xsi:type="xsd:integer"><xsl:value-of select="year-from-date(current-date())"/></Val>
            </Column>
            <!-- copies all nodes of the current Row (the mont  h-total columns of the current month) -->
            <xsl:copy-of select="current-group()"/>
        </Row>
    </xsl:for-each-group>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="node() | @*">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```